How do some Hunter’s Tricks work when used by an animal companion?
Hunter's animal companion can use hunter's tricks from ranger skirmisher archetype.

A hunter may teach her companion hunter’s tricks from the skirmisher ranger archetype (Pathfinder RPG Advanced Player’s Guide 128) instead of standard tricks. The animal companion can use skirmisher tricks when commanded, a number of times per day equal to half its Hit Dice plus its Wisdom modifier.

link
However, some of these tricks when used by a ranger affect the ranger's animal companion.
For example:

Bolster Companion (Ex): The ranger can use this trick as an immediate action when his animal companion is hit with an attack or a combat maneuver. The companion’s AC and combat maneuver defense increase by +4 for the purposes of that attack. If the attack still hits, the animal companion only takes half damage (if any). The animal companion must be able to see and hear the ranger to benefit from this trick.

link
But how do they work when used by a companion?
I can think of at least several variants:

These tricks can't be used because the animal companion doesn't have an animal companion of it's own.
These tricks affect the animal companion that used them.
These tricks affect someone else.

So, which one is right, if any?

The animal companion cannot use these tricks.
Since there is no additional clarification on how the animal companion uses these tricks, it must be assumed that the animal companion uses them as though it were a Skirmisher itself.  Thus, in the trick descriptions, "the ranger" must refer to the animal companion using the trick, and any animal companion mentioned by a trick must logically be the animal companion's animal companion.
This means that the animal companion cannot use Bolster Companion or Heel, since both of these abilities trigger off of an action taken by the (nonexistant) animal companion.  The animal companion could technically use Sic 'Em, but it would have no effect because it has no target.
